# Java populating an ArrayList with objects?

Tags: java, arraylist

Hi I've been following an online example, but the site is down (typical). I'm having trouble with populating my array-list with the objects I created and I'm not sure if I missed something from the example.

the problem is my log produces a 0 size each time?

```
m_excersizes = new ArrayList<Excersize>();
Excersize e1 = new Excersize();
e1.setExcersizeOn("no 1");
e1.setExcersizeTitle("title 1");


Excersize e2 = new Excersize();
e2.setExcersizeOn("no 1");
e2.setExcersizeTitle("title 1");

Log.i("ARRAY", "This many: "+ m_excersizes.size());
```

cheers for any help.

Comment: you missed adding those objects into arraylist. (it is not automatic) use m_excersizes.add(e1); m_excersizes.add(e2);

Comment: because you never add `Excersize` into your list

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You forgot to add the element to the list: `mExcersizes.add(e1);`

(Note: underscore-separated variables names are not the accepted convention in Java. Use camelCase)

Answer (score 1):

You never add anything to your list. Add the following lines:

m_excercizes.add(e1);
m_excercizes.add(e2);

And please stick to the Java naming conventions: `exercises` instead of `m_excercizes`. Moreover, the `setExcercizeTitle()` method is part of the class `Excersize`. Naming it this way is redundant. `setTitle()` is sufficient.

Here's the link of the documentation of J2SE: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/

Comment: i'm terrible at sticking to documented conventions, but will try, thanks for your guidance.

Comment: funny you should bring that up. I know (now) how to spell exercise. But it hurts my fingers every time I have to force them into that sequence! can you believe that. ;) I thought coders could get away with bad spelling. Thanks to you I am now reading Java docs and a dictionary!

Answer (score 0):

You haven't added the objects into the Collection, by instantiating object doesnt mean that they would be added to the list.

add() method is used to add the object to list.

So, this should be used:
m_excersizes.add(e1);
m_excersizes.add(e2);